# How to cause QuoteLineItem.OpportunityLineItemId to be populated

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

Salesforce was added in [Version 40](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_api_objects_changed.htm) new field to object QuoteLineItem : OpportunityLineItemId. 
But, despite my org api version is 41 , when I create new Quote this field was not populated. 
Any idea how to cause it to be populated on insert / sync ,  whatever ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your code where you create the Quote and QuoteLineItem to help you out.

Comment: The user creates it from the standard salesforce, and this field was not populated. I just ask how to cause it to be populated